# Couldn't call helper function in controller in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, model-view-controller, casting, magento-1.9

I am trying to call the helper function in controller in Magento 1.9 . But i am getting error

> Object of class Eniture_BoxSizes_Adminhtml_BoxSizeController could not
>   be converted to string

Any body please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in convertion .
Object to array.
Use another method of convertion in yours helper